# web2py How can I use images in radiobuttons generated from a SQLFORM

Tags: web2py

I would like to generate a SQLFORM with radiobuttons using the radiobutton widget as below (code trimmed):

```
db.define_table('tabA',
    Field('name', 'string', length=16, required=True, unique=True, ),
    Field('shape', 'string', length=8, default='star', widget=SQLFORM.widgets.radio.widget, requires=IS_IN_SET({'star' : '<img src="/myapp/static/images/shapes/star1.png" />'})))
```

My problem is that the image code above gets sanitized and the image tag doesn't show up. Can I turn off the sanitization for SQLFORM somehow? Or is there a different elegant solution to this? My code above shows only 1 radiobutton item for simplicity, but the items are generated dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace `'<img src="/myapp/static/images/shapes/star1.png" />'` with one of the following two options:

- `XML('<img src="/myapp/static/images/shapes/star1.png" />')`
- `IMG(_src='/myapp/static/images/shapes/star1.png')`

Also, it is generally preferable to use the URL() function to generate outgoing URLs. With that replacement, the above two options would change to:

- `XML('<img src="' + URL('static', 'images/shapes/star1.png') + '" />')`
- `IMG(_src=URL('static', 'images/shapes/star1.png'))`

For more information, see the online book topics on [XML()](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/05#XML) and the [IMG helper](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/05#Built-in-Helpers).